# Swap elements in array to reverse an array

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

I got an assignment to reverse an dynamic array in C++. So far, from my logic, I thinking of loop thru the array to reverse it. And here comes my code :

```
int main ()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int num_array[size];

    srand (time(NULL));

    for (int count = 0; count< sizeof(num_array)/sizeof(num_array[0]) ; count++){
        /* generate secret number between 1 and 100: */
        num_array[count] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << num_array[count] << " " ;
    }

    reverse(num_array[size],size);

    cout << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void reverse(int num_array[], int size)
{
    for (int count =0; count< sizeof(num_array)/sizeof(num_array[0]); count++){
        cout << num_array[sizeof(num_array)/sizeof(num_array[0])-1-count] << " " ;
    }

    return;
}
```

Somehow I think my logic was there but this code doesn't works, there's some error. However, my teacher told me that this isn't the way what the question wants. And here is the question :

```
    Write a function reverse that reverses the sequence of elements in an array. For example, if reverse is called with an array containing 1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11,
then the array is changed to 11 9 4 7 9 16 9 4 1.
```

So far, she told us in the reverse method, you need to swap for the array element. So here's my question **how to swap array element so that the array entered would be reversed**?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated portion**

```
    int main ()
{
const int size = 10;
int num_array[size];

srand (time(NULL));

for (int count = 0; count< size ; count++){
    /* generate secret number between 1 and 100: */
    num_array[count] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << num_array[count] << " " ;
}

reverse(num_array,size);

cout << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

```
void reverse(int num_array[], const int& size)
{
for (int count =0; count< size/2; count++){
    int first = num_array[0];
    int last = num_array[count-1];
    int temp = first;
    first = last;
    last = temp;
}
```

}

Comment: Remember that this is probably the only time you have to write it, as C++ already have many nice [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library, including [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: Ya but my teacher focus on swapping. I just could not think for the logic to swap for element in array. Can you please explain?

Comment: Also, [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), as the one you use for `num_array`, is an extension and not part of C++.

Comment: Well there is [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) of course, but I don't think your teacher would like you to use that. The most common and simplest way to swap two values is to assign one to the other and the opposite, remembering not to overwrite any of the original values.

Comment: Also I getting what cannot convert parameter 3 from the reverse method there.

Comment: By the way, you have an even more serious error in your code, that won't show up until you try to run your program, and that is that you are using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer. Once you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer. Even if you specify the argument in array-notation (like `int array[]`) it's still a pointer. And using `sizeof` on the pointer will return the size of the pointer and not what it points to. That's why you have the `size` argument, to say how many elements are in the array.

Comment: You're also calling your `reverse` function with only a single item from the array, and one that is beyond the end of the array.

Comment: So how could I fix it? I am kind of confuse now. I am a novice and I haven't even learnt pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `reverse` function should look like this:

```
void reverse(int* array, const size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
reverse(num_array, size);
```

Comment: Can you check my updated portion and explain to me what's wrong?

Comment: @Rauryn You don't assign back to the array. You don't need the `first` and `last` variables either, just the `temp`, then assign directly from/to the array. _And_ the index you should switch with isn't `count - 1` (that will give you `-1` when `count` is zero) but `size - count - 1`.

Comment: I getting template parameter is ambiguous at live 21 which is the calling of reverse method in main method. Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to declare the method prototype before the main method. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am no C++ programmer, however I do see an easy solution to this problem. By simply using a for loop and an extra array (of the same size) you should be able to reverse the array with ease.

By using a for loop, starting at the last element of the array, and adding them in sequence to the new array, it should be fairly simple to end up with a reversed array. It would be something like this:

Declare two arrays of the same size (10 it seems)

- Array1 contains your random numbers
- Array2 is empty, but can consist of 10 elements

Also declare an integer, which will keep track of the progression of the for loop, but in the opposite direction. i.e not from the end but from the start.

- Counter = 0

Next you will need to create a for loop to start from the end of the first array, and add the values to the start of the second array. Thus we will create a for loop to do so. The for loop will be something like this:

```
for(int i = lengthOfArray1; i > 0; i--){
    Array2[Counter] = Array1[i]
    Counter++
}
```

If you only wish to print it out, you would not need the counter, or the second array, you will simply use the Array1 elements and print them out with that style of for loop.

That's it. You could set Array1 = Array2 afterward if you wished to keep Array1 the original for some reason. Hope this helps a bit, changing it to C++ is your job on this one unfortunately.

Comment: Okay thanks for the guide but however, my teacher insists to use the swapping for array.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually swapping the elements in the array, you're just printing them out. I assume she wants you to actually change what is stored in the array.

As a hint, go through the array swapping the first and last element, then the 2nd and 2nd last element, etc. You only need to loop for `size/2` too. As you have the `size` variable, just use that instead of all the sizeof stuff you're doing.

Comment: Can you give me some example? And why to loop for size/2 only but not the entire array?

Comment: @Rauryn If you loop over the whole array, you would swap the (for example) first and the last values _twice_, i.e. the end result would be the same as you started out with.

Comment: Think about this: you start at the first element and swap with the last. As you finish the loop, if you loop to size, you reach the last element (former first) and swap it with the first (former last). Now the elements are in the same order as before.

Comment: Oh I kind of get it but how could I translate them into code? Is this correct? for (int count =0; count< size/2; count++){
        int first = num_array[0];
  int last = num_array[count-1];
  int temp = first;
  first = last;
  last = temp;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the function like following

```
void reverse(int A[], int N)
{
  for (int i=0, j=N-1; i<j; i++, j--){
    int t = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = t;
  }
}
```